# AWS Lambda Function : {"message":"Internal Server Error"

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, serverless, usps

Im trying to run the **United States Postal Service's Web Tools**, for converting ZIP Codes into State and City. I created an AWS Lambda function inside the AWS Amplify.
But the Lambda function is always giving me the return message `{"message":"Internal Server Error"}`

Here is my Lambda FUnction Code.

```
const axios = require("axios");

const BASE_URI =
  "http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPITest.dll?API=CityStateLookup&XML=";
const config = {
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "text/xml",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true,
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET",
  },
  method: "get",
};
exports.handler = async function (event, context, callback) {
  // The zipcode is sent by the frontend application. 
  // This is where we use it.
  const zipcode = event.queryStringParameters.zipcode;

  // The xml variable is the string we are going to send to the
  // USPS to request the information
  const xml = `<CityStateLookupRequest USERID="400000000"><ZipCode ID="0"><Zip5>${zipcode}</Zip5></ZipCode></CityStateLookupRequest>`;
  try {
    // Using syntactic sugar (async/await) we send a fetch request
    // with all the required information to the USPS.
    const response = await axios(`${BASE_URI}${xml}`, config);
    // We first check if we got a good response. response.ok is
    // saying "hey backend API, did we receive a good response?"
    if (!response.ok) {
      // If we did get a good response we store the response
      // object in the variable
      return { statusCode: response.status, body: response };
    }
    // Format the response as text because the USPS response is
    // not JSON but XML
    const data = await response.text();
    // Return the response to the frontend where it will be used.
    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: data,
    };
    // Error checking is very important because if we don't get a
    // response this is what we will use to troubleshoot problems
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Error: ", err);
    return {
      statusCode: 500,
      body: JSON.stringify({ msg: err.message }),
    };
  }
};
```

The `axios` is working fine I think.

Any help would be appreciated as I'm trying to solve this for days now.

Comment: Did you check the function logs in cloudwatch?

Comment: "errorType": "Error",
    "errorMessage": "Unable to stringify response body",

Answer (score 0):

By default Lambda functions does not have outbound access to internet.
You can add a Nat Gateway to your VPC but it's not cheap.